# Bash script gives "command not found" error on if elif statements

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Now before you flag this as a duplicate please understand i did search for this problem and i already tried all of the solutions to no effect.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the number 3"
read t1
if [$t1 -eq 3]; then
    echo "it is 3"
elif [$t1 > 3]; then
    echo "it is greater than 3"
fi

exit 0
```

The error i get is:

```
./g.sh: line 5: [3: command not found
./g.sh: line 7: [3: command not found
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

spaces needed  `if [ $t1 -eq 3 ]`

Comment: you gotta be kidding me... Bash is one picky SOB.

Comment: @SkiloSkilo it's not bash - `[` is its own executable. It lives in `/bin` on my Mac, may be elsewhere in Linux. Program names always need spaces around them.

Comment: In this case `[` is fine, however if your variable isn't in quotes or you want pattern matching, then use `[[` http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/l-bash-test/index.html